# Iphone OS4 MoviePlayer problem

Tags: iphone

Im having a problem with the MoviePlayer example on iphone os 4.0. For some reason it does not playback video on the simulator or the device. Does any one know why this happens and what changed in iOS4 to break this sample ?. Fixed code could be useful.

Thanks in advance.